# Select ID of available time slot for booking an appointment

Tags: sql, timeslots

I have a table called Appointments displaying time slots for booking an appointment.

```
id | time start | time end | caseno
1  |  800       | 830      | null
2  |  800       | 830      | null
3  |  900       | 930      | AB-111
4  |  900       | 930      | null
```

I need to display available appointment slots where `CaseNo` is null. However, there are two time slots available each time (8am, 830am, 900am, etc.).

What query do I use to display the columns: `Apn_Id`, `Apn_TimeStart` and `Apn_TimeEnd` avoiding to display duplicates and only taking available time slots (`caseno = null`)?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? What's the expected result? Can you show us your current query?

Comment: For the data sample in your question what is the expected result that you are looking for??

Comment: Does the query contain start and end time?

Comment: Please demonstrate that you have tried something.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT MIN(id) as id,time_start,time_end
FROM Appointments 
GROUP BY time_start,time_end
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN caseno IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

**Explanation:**

`Having` clause is for taking only the available time slots (`case = null`).

`MIN` is for `GROUP BY` (to avoid duplicates).

Result:

```
id  time_start  time_end
------------------------
1   800         830
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2814d/1).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find appointments that are `NULL`, a `HAVING` clause is the way to go.  If you want *all* slots to be `NULL`, then use:

```
HAVING COUNT(caseno) = 0
```

If you want *any* slot to be 'NULL`, then use:

```
HAVING COUNT(caseno) < COUNT(*)
```

Remember:  `COUNT(<column name>)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values in the column.